# How to Post a List obtained from ng-repeat to api in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

**HTML**

```
<body class="res layout-subpage" ng-app="cartApp" ng-controller="cartController">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">Image</td>
                <td class="text-left">Product Name</td>
                <td class="text-left">Product Id</td>
                <td class="text-left">Quantity</td>
                <td class="text-right">Unit Price in (&#x20B9;)</td>
                <td class="text-right">Total </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="cartItems">
            <tr ng-repeat="product in productsInCart">
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a href="product.html"><img width="70px" src="{{product.ProductImage}}" alt="{{product.ProductName}}" title="Xitefun Causal Wear Fancy Shoes" class="img-thumbnail" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left"><a href="product.html">{{product.ProductName}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left" ng-model="product.price">{{product.pid}}</td>
                <td class="text-left" width="200px">
                    <div class="input-group btn-block quantity">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{product.qty}}" ng-model="product.qty" ng-text-change="UpdateItemPrice(product)" size="1" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                            <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></button>
                                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeProductFromCart(product.pid)" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                                                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right" ng-model="products.price">{{product.price}}</td>
                <td class="text-right" ng-model="product.itemTotal">{{product.price * product.qty}}
                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="product.itemTotal" value="{{product.price * product.qty}}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**angular controller**

```
var cartApp = angular.module('cartApp', []);
cartApp.controller("cartController", ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.PostCartDataforOffers = function() {
        var listInput = element(by.model('product'));
        $scope.productsInCart = [];
        angular.forEach($scope, function(value, index) {
            $scope.productsInCart.push({
                shoppedetail: {
                    pid: value.pid,
                    price: value.price,
                    qty: value.qty,
                    tp: value.total
                }
            });
        });
        $scope.productsInCart.push({
            shoppedetail: {
                pid: products.pid,
                price: products.price,
                qty: products.qty,
                tp: products.total
            }
        });
        //$scope.productsInCart.push(products);
        $http({
            url: '/Cart/Details',
            method: 'Post',
            data: $scope.productsInCart,
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
}]);
```

Now I want to post these rows as a list in MVC model.
Data successfully retrieved from Object and displayed in table row but I want to post this multiple row as a list in a controller as a MVC Model. Basically this is a cart items that I need to be post on server.

Comment: What server side stack are you using?

Comment: I am using localstorage to render this data in HTML. var cartValue = localStorage.getItem("cartItems");
        cartValue = '[' + cartValue + ']';
        console.log(cartValue);
        var cartObj = JSON.parse(cartValue);
        $scope.productsInCart = cartObj;

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.PostCartDataforOffers = function (productsInCart)
        {
            $scope.productsArray = [];
            var tid = parseInt($cookies.get('TenantId'));
            angular.forEach(productsInCart, function (value, index) {
                value.tp = value.price * value.qty;
                $scope.productsArray.push({ pid: value.pid, price: value.price, qty: value.qty, tp: value.tp });
            });
            $scope.Order = [];
            $scope.Order.push({ "ti": tid, "shoppedetail": $scope.productsArray });
            var OrderString = JSON.stringify($scope.Order);
            var model = OrderString.slice(1, -1);

            $http({
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
                url: "/Cart/Checkout",
                method: 'POST',
                data: model
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
        }
```

Comment: need to convert $scope.Order into JSON String and then remove '[' and ']' from first and last position of Json String.